# Add values from MySql database to an array through a loop

Tags: php

I have been trying to set a while loop to add all the ids in which the user has 20 days into an array. Currently, it displays an error of undefined offset. How can I code the code so that it first gets the id of the first row with 20 days in the lastSeen column, then, second, the ids of the second row and then adds them to the array?

```
$get_email = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE lastSeen='20'" );
$email = mysqli_fetch_array($get_email);
$num_days = mysqli_num_rows($get_email);
$i = 1; 
$array_id = array();
while($i <= $num_days){
array_push($array_id, $email[$i]);
$i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) does not return all the result set as you might think. The documentation says: *"Fetch a result row..."*. This means you have to call it again and again in the loop to get all the rows.

Comment: @axiac What can I replace it with to get the intended results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code is confusing. You get IDs from the database but the names of the variables tell "email". Try to be consistent, it will help you later, when you read this code again.

Since you don't do any processing with the values you get from the database, you can use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). It returns all the rows from the record set at once in an array. Passing `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as its second argument tells it to use the column names (from the `SELECT` clause of the query) as keys in the arrays it creates from each row of the result set.

Next, the PHP function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) extracts only the values of column `id` into a new array that contains exactly the values you need:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE lastSeen='20'");
// Get all the rows, indexed by column names
$rows   = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// Get only the 'id' column
$ids    = array_column($rows, 'id');
```